# Unable to access the WCF service over VPN!

Tags: web-services, wcf, vpn

Heres the scenario, im on a network A, and i use a vpn client to connect network B to access the webservice which can be accessed in network B.Even though im connect to network B , im unable to access the webservice link.Do i need to configure any settings.

But if u r originally in network B and even though if u have connected to network A using vpn client, im able to access the webservice link. But the other way isnt working.

Comment: I voted to close because I think this is really a network-related issue. I would repost it on serverfault.com where you'll find people that are much more helpful at issues such as VPN configuration.

Comment: alright if you say so, thanks :)